# How to shows a surfaceview in android service?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to shows video in WallpaperService.

I suspect the SurfaceHolder created in engine does not has surfaceView, which I need to show video.

I am going to create a new SurfaceView "mSurfaceView", such as

```
mSurfaceView= (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
mHolder1 = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
```

But Android's Service does not have method findViewById.
Also, how can I make wallpaperService display mHolder1?